# Java Spark SQL, how to merge 3 datasets like 1&&(2||3)？These datasets have exactly same columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I need to filter out rows based on 3 rules, and there are correlations between them.

Basically, the final dataset should match rule1&&(rule2||rule3).

1. If pid is "aaa" for all the rows in col1, then filter out all of them.
2. If pid is "aaa" and col1 is null, then filter it out.
3. If pid is "aaa" for all rows in (col2 and col3) key, then filter it out.

Example:

```
pid      col1            col2                 col3  
abaa     111             apple                red
aaa      111             apple                red 
aaa      222             banana               yellow
aaa      222             apple                green  
aaa      333             apple                green
aaa      333             null                 green
aaa      444             apple                red
```

1&&(2||3) = (1&&2)||(1&&3)

Row：

```
aaa      333             null                 green
```

satisfied rule1&2, should be filter out.

Rows:

```
no_fdl      222             banana               yellow
no_fdl      222             apple                green  
no_fdl      333             apple                green
no_fdl      444             apple                red
```

satisfied rule1&3, should be filter out.

And union those filter out rows, then what's left are

```
acc_id      netg_set_id     netting_id           gfcid  
abaa        111             apple                red
no_fdl      111             apple                red
```

How can I filter out these at same time to get correct answer by using spark api？

Comment: Can you also add an example of tables that you have and what you want them to be? It's much easier for us to understand and suggest things

Comment: Just updated with an example